# How do I put content in between specific parts of a PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP that outputs the contents of my array.

What I want to do is echo out the array with commas in between and put an 'and' before the last in the array.

The code currently outputs say: "Cats Dogs Mice Lizards"

I want it to output: "Cats, Dogs, Mice and Lizards".

Am I able to tell it to add a comma after each array output, apart from the last one and replace it with "and"?

Or do I need to split up the array and treat them all up to the penultimate as one part and then the last in the array as another part?

Thanks for any help.

```
<?php 
    $product = get_field('product');
    $products_sold = get_field('products_sold');
    $arraylength = count($products_sold);
    if ($product == "Pets") {
        for($x = 0; $x < $arraylength; $x++){
            echo $products_sold[$x] . "<br />";
        }
    } else {
        echo "The product is not a pet";
    }           
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a foreach to loop over that array using this form

```
foreach ( $array as $index => $value )
```

This allows you to test the `$index` against the `count($array)` like so

```
<?php 
    $product = get_field('product');
    $products_sold = get_field('products_sold');
    $arraylength = count($products_sold);
    if ($product == "Pets") {

        $htm = '';
        foreach ($products_sold as $idx => $val ) {
            if ( $idx < count($products_sold) -1) {
                $htm .= "$val, ";
            } else {
                $htm = rtrim($htm, ', ');
                $htm .= " and $val<br />";
            }
        }
        echo $htm;

    } else {
        echo "The product is not a pet";
    }           
?>
```

Comment: This works beautifully. How would I change it to remove the last comma?

Comment: I made a small amendment to allow the removal of the odd comma, see if that works for you

Comment: Still puts the comma in. I tried removing "} else {" thinking that might work but that ruins it!

Comment: **silly me** I botched the `rtrim()` have another look

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you so much for this!

Comment: Why calculate `count($products_sold)` in each iteration - is it going to change? And since the keys seem to be numeric, can't you just `for(..)` for the `1..n-1` elements and add the last? (would save the if inside the for altogether)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have different behaviour for the last element, consider changing [Amitabh Deotale's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34313168/1557526) to something using [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop)

```
$last = array_pop($arrayname);
$string = sprintf("%s and %s", implode(", ", $arrayname), $last);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`implode`](http://php.net/implode) function, for example

```
implode(",",$arrayname);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array_pop()` to get the last element of your array.

```
$array = get_your_array();
$last_el = array_pop($array);

echo join(",", $array) . " and " . $last_el;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following block of code:

```
  for($x = 0; $x < $arraylength; $x++){
    $seprator = "";
    if ($x < $arraylength)
    {
        $seprator = ",";
        if ($x == ($arraylength-1))
            $seprator = "and";
    }  // Manage seprator after echo
    echo $products_sold[$x] . $seprator . "<br />";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do simply:

```
  $pets = array("Cats", "Dogs", "Mice", "Lizards");
  foreach ($pets as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == count($pets) - 1) $final .= "and " . $value.".";
    else $final .= $value.", ";
  }
  echo $final;
```